# "Error in port widths or dimensions" while producting 1x3 and 3x3 matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

The Matlab function named `C` generates a matrix with 3x3 dimension. I have to product it with the vector 1x3 made with the mux of sources `n_x`, `n_y`, `n_z`.

[image]

However, running this model causes two errors:

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Invalid dimension has been
>   specified for input port 2 of 'untitled/Product'.
>
> Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'untitled/C' is a
>   [3x3] matrix.

Could you please explain me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. All I had to do is to swap the production block inputs and set the `Matrix*` value in "Multiplication" property in the block settings.

[image]

Comment: note that you can accept your own answer, to prevent other people from  trying to answer your question.